# JMeter report metrics of each request

Tags: performance, jmeter, measure, response-time

Is possible with JMeter report data of all test request? Most important are `Response time` and `Thoughput` for me. When I use graph or aggregate report, I get only final values of `Average` and `Thoughput` on the end of the test. But I need save `response time` and `thoughput` for each request of the test. Exist some tool in JMeter for reporting and saving these metrics for each request of test? Graph display these metrics by lines, but I need these metrics as numbers. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Jmeter plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org)** for more better graphs, which gives composite graph option by which you can get  combined response time graph and byte throughput graph (and more graphs) together.

Comment: And allows these plugins number representation and saving these metrics? I need number values of these metrics for analysis in NCSS. So I need all values of these metrics as numbers in f.e. table or csv.

Comment: @OndřejRyška: refer this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_listeners.htm

Comment: Thanks! This link is very helpful. Chapter "Default Configuration" resolve my problem.